# WCF Transport security with peertrust and self-signed client certificates

Tags: .net, wcf, certificate, self-signed

I'm been struggling with WCF for a while now and I can't seem to figure it out.
I have a self-hosted WCF service with SSL enabled (using a signed certificate from a self-signed root CA), so far so good. The service is for business-to-business communication so certificates seemed to be the best solution.

(I'm using the WS binding at the moment but that's just for development purposes since all binding methods support (as far as I know) transport level security with client certificates.)

Some relevant configuration bits for the service:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<!-- snip -->

<serviceCredentials>
  <clientCertificate>
     <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="CurrentUser" />
  </clientCertificate>
</serviceCredentials>
```

When I have the client use a self-signed certificate which is in the "trusted people" store of the user running the WCF service it fails. When I use a certificate signed by my own root CA it works even if it's not in the "trusted people" store.

I was expecting that I would be able to use self-signed certificates, store them in the "trusted people" store and things would just work. But there seems to be some extra validation going on, it there something I'm missing? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with the same problem wherein my self-signed client certificate would be validated even though it was not in the "Trusted People" store, despite the validation mode of "PeerTrust".  I was finally able to restrict the service to accept *only* the specific client certificate by using the following service behaviors:

```
<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior ...>
      ...
         <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
               <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"
                               revocationMode="NoCheck" 
                               trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
               <certificate findValue="NameOfClientCertificate"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="TrustedPeople" />
            </clientCertificate>
         </serviceCredentials>
         ...
      </behavior>
      ...
```

Both the authentication element and the certificate element were required to point to the correct store, in this case "LocalMachine".

Answer (score 0):

Right, so, transport security and certificate validation is handled at a lower level which WCF has no control over. So all those fancy things with custom validators etc don't work with transport security, only message security.
To restrict access from clients while still using only transport security you need to set up a CTL (Certificate Trust List). The following sites should give you some pointers.

http://www.leastprivilege.com/CertificateBasedAuthenticationAndWCFTransportSecurity.aspx
http://viisual.net/configuration/IIS7-CTLs.htm

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work using these lines of code:

```
m_host = gcnew WebServiceHost( IService::typeid, baseAddress );
....
m_host->Credentials->ClientCertificate->Authentication->CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode::Custom;  //PeerTrust did not work here
m_host->Credentials->ClientCertificate->Authentication->CustomCertificateValidator = System::IdentityModel::Selectors::X509CertificateValidator::PeerTrust;
```

Looks like WCF bug to me.